# How do I check if the numlock key is turned on in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm detecting keystrokes within a function like FocusNode 's onKey callback.
At this time, I'm trying to check if the numLock key is on, but it doesn't seem to work.
flutter version is 2.5.

```dart
// RawKeyEvent event
event.data.isModifierPressed(ModifierKey.numLockModifier);
```

Comment: `isModifierPressed()` returns true when both keys are pressed - for example if you pressed `x` key only it returns `false` but if you press `x` key while `numlock` was also pressed then it returns `true`

Comment: Is there no way to check if numlock is currently on?

Comment: i dont think so